# MySql from VS 2017 Unable to create Entity Models from database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I am unable to create Entity Models from database.

It is first time using MySQL from VS2017.

I am following tutorial at

1)  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html

2)  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

3)  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

I installed MySQL on local machine. I installed NuGet packages MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity, and  MySql.Web (all version 6.9.11).

In tutorial No.2, while adding “ADO.Net Entity Data Model”,  I get upto this window

[image]

**I click next and then window silently close without producing any Data Models.**

***This means I don’t see the window below.***

[image]

I assume my connection strting and web.config file is OK as I can successfully execute code bellow and get result “Samoa -- Malietoa Tanumafili II”

`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class Tutorial2
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT Name, HeadOfState FROM Country WHERE Continent='Oceania'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]+" -- "+rdr[1]);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}`
```

Please guide what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in MySQL Connector/NET: [bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338). According to that bug report, there's a bug in the wizard code that should be fixed in the next version, 6.10.7.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bradley, So it was not my inexperience (alone) with MySQL but it "IS" an issue. Any way updating VS 2017 to 15.6.6 and using version 6.9.11 of MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity remove this problem.